# How did Gilles Peterson persuade Mala to "Mala in Cuba"?

Tags: electronic-music

I've read in several reviews that BBC1 radio DJ Gilles Peterson gave the inspiration for dubstep artist Mala to record "Mala in Cuba".

> [Challenged by musical sage Gilles Peterson to mix soundsystem culture with the traditional melodies and instruments of Cuban music, Mala traveled to Havana to retrieve those sounds from their source.](https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/17202-mala-in-cuba/)

and

> [In 2011, London dubstep producer Mala travelled to Havana at the behest of Gilles Peterson to collaborate with Cuban musicians.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/reviews/fdj9/)

Now, I'm a little incredulous how this story went, but couldn't find any details. First, I'm not aware that Dubstep has any particular links to Cuba, much more so to Jamaika and its Reggae music. Second, why did Mala trust Peterson that this is a good idea?

I think the album that came out of this is absolutely fantastic, but I would really like to know the background of this endeavour.